# Rotate 3D earth scnnode to specific lat long swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode, virtual-earth

I have created a scnnode for earth view with lat long on it. Now i want to rotate earth on specific city lat long and that city lat long should be visible on center of screen to user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user is facing N0 E0 point, rotate earth node around screen vertical axis by longitude angle  then around screen horizontal axis by latitude angle